# What are the meaning the nomenclature in high cell density cultivation for the production of a protein?

Tags: cell-culture, biotechnology, fermentation

I'd like to know the meaning of these terms in a HCDC studies of a modified strain.
Max specific yield (mg/g DCW)
Max volumetric product yield (g/l)
Specific product formation rate Qp (mg/g DCW/h)

Comment: I wanted only the definitions of each

Answer (score 1):

Maximum specific yield = milligram product per gram dry cell weight (DCW).
Maximum volumetric yield = gram product per liter culture.
Specific product formation rate Qp = milligram product per gram dry cell weight per hour.